# How to attach dynamic value to multiple rows in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following table

```
id lang title
1   en   Hello
1   de   Hallo
1   it   Ciao
2   de   Tschüss
2   ko   안녕
```

The key of this table is `(id,lang)`
I want to write a query that adds a column `title_en` so that for each row it will bring the `id` of the `lang=en`

Output should be:

```
id lang title   title_en
1   en   Hello   Hello
1   de   Hallo   Hello
1   it   Ciao    Hello
2   de   Tschüss null
2   ko   안녕     null
```

How can this be done in Presto?

Comment: Self LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain sql. Should work for Presto

```
SELECT T.*, T2.TITLE AS title_en
FROM your_table T
LEFT JOIN your_table T2
  ON T.ID = T2.ID
 AND T2.LANG = 'en'
```